# What are the best practices in testing a TitanDB graph

Tags: unit-testing, titan

As the question suggests, i wanted to know what are the best practices/recommendations to test TitanDB graph? (primarily unit-testing)

The graph I talk about is having <100k nodes and <200k edges so fits in-memory quite nicely.

P.S : This is a slightly subjective question, but should be beneficial to the community.

Answer (score 1):

If your primarily unit testing traversals that read from the graph AND your graph data is static, then for a graph of that size you might consider loading it all once at the start of all tests then sharing that graph instance among your tests.  If that is not the nature of your graph, then an [in-memory instance](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/inmemorystorage.html) is probably best as you can set that up and tear it down as needed.

In short, from config you can do:

```
storage.backend=inmemory
```

or programmtically:

```
g = TitanFactory.build().set('storage.backend','inmemory').open()
```